# (Roblox Studio) how do I get my textbox to actually change the "text" to whatever someone types in it?

Tags: lua, roblox

In my Roblox game I want to have the material of the walls change to what a player types into an in-game textbox. The text property of the Roblox in-game textbox does not update, when a player types in it. The text just appears on the surface.

How can I get the text property to update?

Comment: Heyo, could you share your code? It may be worth taking a moment and reading the [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) article, and then updating your question.

Comment: Sure, I’ll read up on that. Sorry about that issue, I’ll be sure to edit the question shortly. -TheCubeN00B

Comment: Also, how would I add code without it staying on nit a few lines? How would I format it like actual code?

Comment: Check out the guide on [Markdown Help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code). I always just add 4 spaces in front of each code line.

Answer (score 0):

If youre talking about the SurfaceGui then the problem is likely that the SurfaceGui is not inside the PlayerGui, TextBox is modified by the client so the SurfaceGui needs to be inside the PlayerGui, also put the adornee to the part so that it shows on the part.